# How to pass arguments to thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

all
I have searched this question, and I found so many answers to it was not difficult to find a solution for my question.
BUT, I have strange experience and I don't know the reason that's why I ask people to give me some advice.
Here are my codes:

```
    void SetThread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _intArrayLength; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("SetThread->i: {0}\r\n", i));
            _th[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => RunThread(i)));
            _th[i].Start();
        }
    }

    void RunThread(int num)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("RunThread->num: {0}\r\n", num));
    }
```

Yes, they are ordinary thread codes.
I expect all the thread array should be calling RunThread method 10 times.
It should be like

```
SetThread->i: 0
SetThread->i: 1
SetThread->i: 2
SetThread->i: 3
SetThread->i: 4
SetThread->i: 5
SetThread->i: 6
SetThread->i: 7
SetThread->i: 8
SetThread->i: 9
RunThread->num: 0
RunThread->num: 1
RunThread->num: 2
RunThread->num: 3
RunThread->num: 4
RunThread->num: 5
RunThread->num: 6
RunThread->num: 7
RunThread->num: 8
RunThread->num: 9
```

This is what I expect to be. The order is not important.
But I get the result like below.

```
SetThread->i: 0
SetThread->i: 1
SetThread->i: 2
The thread '<No Name>' (0x18e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x11ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1190) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1708) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xc94) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xdac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x12d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1574) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1138) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xef0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
SetThread->i: 3
RunThread->num: 3
RunThread->num: 3
RunThread->num: 3
SetThread->i: 4
RunThread->num: 4
SetThread->i: 5
SetThread->i: 6
RunThread->num: 6
RunThread->num: 6
SetThread->i: 7
RunThread->num: 7
SetThread->i: 8
RunThread->num: 8
SetThread->i: 9
RunThread->num: 9
RunThread->num: 10
```

What I expect is that RunThread function should carry the argument(num) from 0 to 9.
And I cannot figure out what that error message is.
"The thread '' ~~ and so on.
Could anyone give me some clue on this?

Comment: The error message means nothing, it's just debugging output from Visual Studio I think.

Comment: Also, all the threads refer to the loop counter `i` through a closure. (Created by the lambda you pass to `ThreadStart`.) They do not get a copy of the current value of `i` when the `Thread` object is created, but the value of `i` when `RunThread` is finally called, which happens later after you start the thread and it finishes initialising etc - the loop will have progressed at that point. As you see from your output, that's exactly what happens, `RunThread` prints out the last value seen in `SetThread`.

Comment: Anyway, I *think* you can prevent this by doing `var ii = i;` inside the `for` loop, and using `ii` in the argument to `ThreadStart`. That will make the lambdas close over different "instances" of the local variable. (The difference is that the loop counter's scope is outside the loop body, a local variable inside.) Unless I'm confusing things with Javascript.

Comment: A common problem, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Interesting, from MSDN: We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop will not be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are [creating a closure over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) - an easy fix is to just create a local copy, so your thread uses the desired value:

```
void SetThread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _intArrayLength; i++)
        {
           int currentValue = i;
            Console.Write(string.Format("SetThread->i: {0}\r\n", i));
            _th[i] = new Thread(() => RunThread(currentValue));
            _th[i].Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sorry for the late response

Answer (score 3):

You may want to change your code like this to use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) delegate:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _intArrayLength; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("SetThread->i: {0}\r\n", i));
        _th[i] = new Thread((a) => RunThread((int)a));
        _th[i].Start(i);
    }
```

Otherwise, from your thread entry point delegate `() => RunThread(i)` you're accessing the variable `i` from the parent main thread's context, which may change before your new thread may even start.

Comment: Parameterized threads are kind of obsolete since the arrival of lambdas.

Comment: @usr, I don't think these two things are related. A lambda expression is still used in my code above as a shortcut, but I could rewrite it _without_ lambda yet _without_ parametrizing the thread start, similar to how @BrokenGlass did it: `new Thread(delegate() { RunThread(currentValue); })`

Comment: Imprecise wording on my part. I meant closures in whatever way C# supports them.

Comment: @usr, I agree. It's all about how anonymous delegates deal with the variables defined in the same scope. As [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2006/08/08/692346.aspx) excellent series of blog posts call them, _the easy kind and the hard kind_. One minor advantage of parametrizing a delegate might be that, as long as it doesn't use its parent scope local variables, there is no behind-the-scene creation of an anonymous class by compiler (and a runtime instance of it), which is otherwise involved to support the syntax benefits. I still use it for simple cases like the above :)